# Join files using Apache Spark / Spark SQL

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to use Apache Spark for comparing two different files based on some common field, and get the values from both files and write it as output file.

I am using Spark SQL for joining both files (after storing the RDD as table).

Is this the correct approach?

Can we `compare / join` files without Apache SQL?

Please suggest me on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use plain spark you can join two RDDs.

```
let a = RDD<Tuple2<K,T>>
let b = RDD<Tuple2<K,S>>
RDD<Tuple2<K,Tuple2<S,T>>> c = a.join(b)
```

This produces an RDD of every pair for key K. There are also leftOuterJoin, rightOuterJoin, and fullOuterJoin methods on RDD.

So you have to map both datasets to produce two RDD's indexed by your common key, then join them. Here is the [documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/programming-guide.html#transformations) i'm referencing.

Comment: Thanks. Is it possible to get only required fields from both files not all the fields? what is the transformation we should use to get it?

Answer (score 1):

Try doing inner join between two dataframes of data sets for matched records.